# Azure add external AD to B2C

Tags: .net, azure, api, identity

i would like create login to Azure in my web app. I create B2C tenant and it works perfect on custom account. Now i would like add external AD to enable login external users from external AD. I use this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow
It working. But it's very circumstantial, i need set many thing and external provider too must set much things.

Is it good way? Or is there any other way? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add authentication functionality to your web app, you don't need to use it in B2C; you can configure authentication in Azure WebApp with many providers like this.

[image]

Here is the link to the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service